# Gulp tasks not finish but works correctly

Tags: javascript, gulp

I run the task below, the task does not finish but the task works correctly. I use manually callback but nothing changes.

```
gulp.task('compileSrc',
    function () {
        const imgFilter = plugin.filter('**/*.{jpg,png,gif}', {restore: true});
        const fontFilter = plugin.filter('**/*.{ttf,woff,woff2,eot,svg}', {restore: true});
        const cssFilter = plugin.filter('**/*.css', {restore: true});
        const jsFilter = plugin.filter('**/*.js', {restore: true});
        const htmlFilter = plugin.filter('**/*.html', {restore: true});

        return gulp.src([paths.src + '/css/**/*.css', paths.src + '/fonts/**/*', paths.src + '/img/**/*', paths.app + '/**/*'])
        // CSS ******************************************************************
            .pipe(cssFilter)
            .pipe(plugin.concat('app.css'))                   // merge all css file to one file
            // min css file
            .pipe(
                plugin.minCss({
                    compatibility: 'ie8',
                    keepSpecialComments: false
                })
            )
            // rename css file
            .pipe(
                plugin.rename({
                    suffix: '.min'
                })
            )
            .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.dist + '/src/css'))          // save to hard file
            .pipe(cssFilter.restore)
            // Html Template ******************************************************************
            .pipe(htmlFilter)
            /* minify html */
            .pipe(
                plugin.minHtml({
                    collapseWhitespace: true,
                    removeComments: true
                })
            )
            /* convert html file to angular template cache */
            .pipe(
                plugin.templateCache({
                    module: 'rainCrm',
                    root: paths.app
                })
            )
            .pipe(htmlFilter.restore)
            // JS ******************************************************************
            .pipe(jsFilter)
            .pipe(plugin.ngAnnotate())
            .pipe(plugin.angularFilesort())           // sort angular files
            .pipe(plugin.concat('app.js'))            // merge all js file to one file
            .pipe(plugin.minJs())                     // min js file
            // rename js file
            .pipe(
                plugin.rename({
                    suffix: '.min'
                })
            )
            .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.dist + '/src/js'))          // save to hard file
            .pipe(jsFilter.restore)
            // IMG ******************************************************************
            .pipe(imgFilter)
            .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.dist + '/src/img'))         // save to hard file
            .pipe(imgFilter.restore)
            // FONT ******************************************************************
            .pipe(fontFilter)
            .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.dist + '/src/fonts'));       // save to hard file
    }
);
```

result:

```
[00:24:18] Starting 'compileSrc'...

Process finished with exit code 0
```

but below task finish correct.

```
/* compile libraries */
gulp.task('compileLibs',
    function () {
        const jsFilter = plugin.filter('**/*.js', {restore: true});
        const cssFilter = plugin.filter('**/*.css', {restore: true});

        return gulp.src(
            plugin.mainBowerFiles({
                overrides: {
                    "font-awesome": {
                        main: [
                            "css/font-awesome.min.css",
                            "fonts/**/*"
                        ]
                    },
                    "persian-date": {
                        main: [
                            "dist/0.1.8/persian-date-0.1.8.js"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            })
        )
        // CSS ******************************************************************
            .pipe(cssFilter)
            .pipe(plugin.concat('libs.css'))          // merge all css file to one file
            // min css file
            .pipe(
                plugin.minCss({
                    compatibility: 'ie8',
                    keepSpecialComments: false
                })
            )
            // rename css file
            .pipe(
                plugin.rename({
                    suffix: '.min'
                })
            )
            .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.dist + '/src/css'))
            .pipe(cssFilter.restore)
            // JS ******************************************************************
            .pipe(jsFilter)
            .pipe(plugin.concat('libs.js'))            // merge all js file to one file
            .pipe(plugin.minJs())                         // min js file
            // rename css file
            .pipe(
                plugin.rename({
                    suffix: '.min'
                })
            )
            .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.dist + '/src/js'))
            .pipe(jsFilter.restore)
            // FONTS ******************************************************************
            .pipe(plugin.filter('**/*.{ttf,woff,woff2,eot,svg,png,jpg,gif}'))
            .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.dist + '/src/fonts'));
    }
);
```

thanks.

Comment: This doesn't directly answer your question, but I would strongly encourage you to break up your gulp tasks into smaller logically cohesive chunks (i.e. `"compileSrc"` is composed of the tasks `"compileStyles"`, `"compileScripts"`, `"compileResources"`). After doing this, the issue will most likely jump out at you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks. I find problem.

```
const fontFilter = plugin.filter('**/*.{ttf,woff,woff2,eot,svg}', {restore: true});
```

must remove restore option from last filter. (problem filter plugin with return stream)

```
const fontFilter = plugin.filter('**/*.{ttf,woff,woff2,eot,svg}');
```